# What day of the week are the most questions posted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, statistics

What day of the week  are the most questions posted on Stack Overflow?

Suppose I login to Stack Overflow once a week, then what will be best time to face the maximum number of questions?

Comment: Um, what? No idea what you mean.

Comment: I guess he's asking at what time most questions are asked.

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question, but I had to make some assumptions about what you meant. Does it still reflect your original question?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/137558/questions-by-timeslice#graph and http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/111009/best-time-to-ask-question#graph ? Though those are time... Day of Week looks like: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/98625/total-posts-created-by-day-of-week#graph

Comment: @hantoun exactly.Suppose I login to stackoverflow once in Week so what will be best time to face maximum no of question

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar the weekend.  Though note that that would also mean you would be *less* likely to get an answer before your question drops off and becomes harder to find.

Answer (score 10):

For questions asked by day of week (modified from https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/98625/total-posts-created-by-day-of-week:

```sql
SELECT DatePart(WEEKDAY, CreationDate), count(Id)
FROM Posts
where posttypeid = 1
GROUP BY DatePart(WEEKDAY, CreationDate)
```

The raw numbers are:

```
- ------- 
1 675616  
2 1267739 
3 1380187 
4 1413296 
5 1402309 
6 1251770 
7 681973
```

Graph (note the Y axis isn't at 0):

[image: by dow]

You can see the weekends are by far the lowest.

Time of day shows various humps in the day as different groups get into work or, get back from lunch.  From https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/137558/questions-by-timeslice#graph

[image]

Comment: Is this time data all in UTC, or is it normalized to each time zone? (Does SO even store time zone info?)

Comment: @AndrewArnold I'd assume its UTC... everything else seems to be.

Answer (score 5):

To get a view of an entire week, I used the following query and some Excel magic to come up with a chart. <sup>Now if only I could get rid of those extra X-axis markers...</sup>

```sql
select
  datepart(weekday, CreationDate) as weekday
  ,datepart(hour, CreationDate) as hour
  ,count(*) as amount
from
  Posts p
where
  p.PostTypeId = 1 -- Question
group by
  datepart(weekday, CreationDate)
  ,datepart(hour, CreationDate)
order by
  weekday
  ,hour
```

[image: chart of data]

Comment: I think I can see people getting out of work early on Friday afternoon...

Comment: @MichaelT I wonder if it would correlate with bad answers because of those devs who go to the bar on Friday lunch?

Comment: @MartinJames the next challenge then, would be to make a box and whisker plot for questions and answers asked at different times of the day based on their score.  Note that you won't be able to get into the deleted posts... but its a start.