# How are question scores correlated with day/time of posting?

Tags: discussion

I've seen some discussion of how [SO traffic varies during the week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272744/what-day-of-the-week-are-the-most-questions-posted-on-stack-overflow), and whether [time of day affects views of a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256290/does-it-matter-what-time-of-day-i-post), and it's quite interesting. No one yet seems to have done any analysis of **correlation between day/time of posting and score**. It seems a promising line of enquiry and at least worth a look (e.g., on a different but related note, anecdotally the best time for an eBay auction to end is Sunday evening).

Here's my attempt.

```
SELECT (DatePart(WEEKDAY, CreationDate)-1)*24+DatePart(HOUR, CreationDate) AS WeekHour, cast(SUM(Score) as float)/cast(count(Id) as float)
FROM Posts
where posttypeid = 1
AND Score>=0
AND Score<10
GROUP BY (DatePart(WEEKDAY, CreationDate)-1)*24+DatePart(HOUR, CreationDate)
ORDER BY WeekHour
```

You'll see that this restricts attention to questions that weren't negatively scored, and weren't attracting high scores either. The graph comes out like this (I put it through OpenOffice Calc for bonus points):

[image: Average score by hour of the week, 0>=score>10]

A few preliminaries:

1. The Y-axis doesn't start at zero. The effect isn't quite as stark as it appears on first sight.
2. The X-axis is how many hours into the week we've gone, in GMT. So it starts at midnight at the beginning of Sunday.
3. Vertical gridlines are therefore midnight each day.

The effect is really quite noticeable. There's not a huge change from one day to the next, but there is a big change as the day goes on. Posts are better off by about 0.2 votes if they're posted at around midnight than if they're posted at around 4am (GMT). And 0.2 votes might not seem colossal, but remember we're only talking about posts with a maximum score of 9.

I tried it for posts that are above the Stack Exchange Threshold of Nice (score of 10+), and there was very little correlation at all.

Why is this happening, do you think? Two obvious possibilities:

1. Better questions get posted around midnight.
2. People respond more positively to questions that are posted around midnight.

(I keep saying midnight, but I'm not blind to the fact that midnight GMT is not midnight for everyone.)

The fact that very highly rated questions are posted at all hours, with no obvious correlation, leans me toward the second. If better questions were written around midnight, you'd think that this would apply to very good questions as well as reasonable but not brilliant ones. On the other hand, it's entirely plausible that *voting* for very good questions will even out in a way that it won't for less good questions, because the very good questions have a longer shelf life. The effective voting period will be much longer for the very good questions, and therefore won't be so much affected by time of posting.

Thoughts?

Anyway, only a couple of hours to prime posting time. *Must go away and think up some mediocre programming questions...*

Comment: It correlates with the number of users that see a post and can therefore vote.  Midnight GMT is when the USA pops their beers, it picks back up when India goes to work.